# f(t)= $\frac{1}{2}$ e^-t (sin (t) - cos (t)) + $\frac{1}{2}$ . Determine the rate of change of mRNA concentration as a function of time.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

hi kind of feel as if im doing this wrong someone please help

the concentration of mRNA in a cell over time is modeled by the function f(t)=$\frac{1}{2}$ e^-t(sin(t)- cos(t))+ $\frac{1}{2}$ .

Determine the rate of change of mRNA concentration as a function of time.

f(t)= $\frac{1}{2}$ e^-t (sin (t) - cos (t)) + $\frac{1}{2}$
= $\frac{1}{2}$ ($\frac{d}{dt}$ (e^-t)(sin(t)-cos(t) + $\frac{1}{2}$) + $\frac{d}{dt}$ (sin(t)-cos(t)+ $\frac{1}{2}$) e^-t)

= cos(t)-(sin(t))+0

= cos(t)+sin(t)

=  $\frac{1}{2}$ (-e^-t)(sin(t)-cos(t) + $\frac{1}{2}$) + (cos (t)+ sin (t)e^-t)

= (1)(-e^t(sin(t)- cos (t)+ $\frac{1}{2}$) + cos (t)+(sin(t)e^-t /2

=  $\frac{-1}{2}$e^-t+2e^-tcos(t)/2

can anyone check if this is right because i don't really understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you lost track of the $\frac 12$ term at the end and put it places that it didn't need to be.

$f(t) = \frac 12 e^{-t}(\sin t-\cos t) + \frac 12$

$f'(t) = \frac {d}{dt}(\frac 12 e^{-t}(\sin t-\cos t) + \frac 12)$

Applying the product rule:

$f'(t) = \frac 12\frac {d}{dt}( e^{-t})\cdot (\sin t-\cos t) + \frac 12 e^{-t}\frac {d}{dt}(\sin t-\cos t)$

The derivative of the constant $\frac 12 = 0$

$f'(t) = -\frac 12( e^{-t})(\sin t-\cos t) + \frac 12 e^{-t}(\cos t + \sin t)$

We can factor out $\frac 12 e^{-t}$ from each term.

$f'(t) = \frac 12( e^{-t})(-\sin t +\cos t  + \cos t+\sin t)\\
f'(t) = \frac 12( e^{-t})(2 \cos t)\\
f'(t) =  e^{-t}\cos t$